# I want to display a calendar using Jquery and datepicker on twig symfony3

Tags: jquery, symfony

This is the form z:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('date ',DateType::class, array(
        ))

        ->add('save',SubmitType::class)
    ;
    ;
}
```

and on the twig file I put:

```
{{form(form)}}
```

So how can I integrate jquery to obtain calender when I click to choose a date?

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a class to you date input in your form builder like this :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('date ',DateType::class, array(
            'attr' => array('class' => 'myDatePickerInput')
        ))
        ->add('save',SubmitType::class)
    ;
}
```

and then in you twig file add some javascript :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
   jQuery(function($) {
        $( ".myDatePickerInput" ).datepicker();
   });
</script>
```

You can check the doc about Jquery Datepicker [here](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)